# Why does velocity along $x$ axis not change as a function of time during projectile motion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, vectors

$U_x$ will be equal to $u\cos\theta $ and $u=\sin\theta$. But in case of final velocity, it is $v\cos\theta$ where $-gt =0$ and $v\sin\theta - gt$.

Why is that ? I am not getting how to solve this.

Comment: Huh???   What *are* you even asking?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork got it now. Forgot to edit

Comment: It is because the gravity pulls *down* (i.e. it only affects the *vertical* movement of the body) but not *sidewise*. There are other forces that normally act on the body in (at least partially) the sidewise direction, such as air resistance, but I presume in this problem you are allowed to ignore them.

Comment: ucos90=0 right ? That what you meant @StinkingBishop

Comment: usin90 = u right @

Comment: I mean, if the body moves with speed $u$ at angle $\theta$ with respect to $x$ axis, then it moves *sidewise* at the velocity $u\cos\theta$ and *upwards* at the velocity $u\sin\theta$. Only the latter component is affected by the gravity and so it changes at rate $g$, i.e. after time $t$ the vertical velocity is $u\sin\theta-gt$. The horizontal component does not change if you ignore other forces than gravity - it stays at $g\cos\theta$.

Comment: Ok.Got it.One more thing , why do we say for the top height of a projectile motion , vy = 0. Why not vx?a@StinkingBishop

Comment: Because the $y$ component of the speed vector is zero. In that instant the body moves only sidewise along the $x$-axis.

Comment: @user102532 When the projectile reaches its highest point, its velocity in the up/down direction is zero. So, it is going to be $v_y$ simply because we seem to have agreed to paint the $x$ axis horizontally and the $y$ axis vertically. Had we agreed to paint them the other way round, or, weirder, to name them $a$ and $b$ axis, or something, of course the symbols would change - but with the convention we used all along, the $y$ axis goes up and down, the $x$ axis goes left and right, and this is why it is $v_y$ and not $v_x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic equation that describes your problem is $$\begin{cases}x(t)=v_0\cos\theta_0t\\y(t)=v_0\sin\theta_0t-\dfrac12gt^2 \end{cases}\to\begin{cases}v_x=v_0\cos\theta_0\\v_y=v_0\sin\theta_0-gt\end{cases}.$$
Let's take a look at the final situation. $y(t)$ is clearly zero, so
$$\tan\theta_0x-\dfrac{gx^2}{2v_0^2\cos^2\theta_0}=0\implies x_{\text{final}}=\dfrac{2v_0^2\cos^2\theta_0\tan\theta_0}{g}=\dfrac{v_0^2\sin(2\theta_0)}{g}$$
$$\implies x_{\text{final,max}}=\dfrac{v_0^2}{g},\theta_0=\pi/4\text{ and }t_{\text{final}}=\dfrac{v_0^2/g\sin(2\theta_0)}{v_0\cos(\theta_0)}$$
$$v_y(t_{\text{final}})=-v_0\sin\theta_0,v_x(t_{\text{final}})=v_0\cos\theta_0$$

Comment: Thanks and congrats on reaching 1K reputation